# Error: "Connection failed: SQLState: '08001' occurs when creating an ODBC connection on Microsoft SQL 2008 r 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two sql server installed in same server.
SQL server 2012 express and SQL server 2008 r2. 
After we moved to new office, we are not able to connect 2008 server but still able to connect 2012.

I have checked and confirmed that TCP/IP is enabled and the port is 1433 for both server.

SQL browser is also enabled

That is no firewall for blocking inbound and outbound from server, however I can't disable end user firewall as the option is being grey out by company IT.

ABC\SQLexpress2012 -  working 
ABC\SQL2008 - doesn't not working

We managed to login Sql management studio in the machine itself. But both NT authentication and SQL authentication are not working in end user PC.

Any ideas from the experts here ?

Comment: Your SQL Servers need to be running on different ports. They aren't both running on 1433. You'll probably find your 2008 server is _not_ running on 1433, _or_ it is trying to and failing because the port is already taken by 2012. Use SQL Server logs to work out what port it's running on, _or_ see if it is failing because the port is in use.

Comment: I believe [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/82007/how-do-i-get-this-sql-server-odbc-connection-working) question and answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. We are managed to connect the server by IP address and tcp port, example 10.150.109.10,1433

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change your SQL Server 2008 port

try this one

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port

Answer (score 0):

I discovered my server had been changed to IPV6, and client was not set up for IPV6.  Disabling IPV6 to force IPV4 aliviated the problem.